# Log every request to web api method to file

Tags: asp.net-mvc, log4net

My requirements are to add logging to every request and response and errors to a file. I have tried this,

```
public class LogRequestAndResponseHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    private static readonly ILog Log = LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);

    protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(
        HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        // log request body
        string requestBody = await request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        Log.Info(requestBody);

        // let other handlers process the request
        var result = await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);

        if (result.Content != null)
        {
            // once response body is ready, log it
            var responseBody = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            Log.Info(responseBody);
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

Added this it to WebApiConfig of MVC5 as following,

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Web API configuration and services

        log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();

        config.MessageHandlers.Add(new LogRequestAndResponseHandler());

        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

Web config has this section,

```
  <log4net>
    <!-- file appender -->
    <appender name="RollingFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
      <file value="C:/logs/my_log_file.log"/>
      <appendToFile value="true"/>
      <rollingStyle value="Date"/>
      <maxSizeRollBackups value="30"/>
      <datePattern value=".yyyy-MM-dd"/>
      <staticLogFileName value="true"/>
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger - %message%newline"/>
      </layout>
    </appender>
    <root>
      <level value="DEBUG"/>
      <appender-ref ref="RollingFileAppender"/>
    </root>
  </log4net>
```

Nothing is being added to file and there are no errors, is there anything I am doing wrong, it creates the file but no logging ever ?

Comment: Check if the path is correct. You sometimes need to add '\\' to path in windows

Comment: it creates the file, just no logging

Comment: Two suggestions - try adding `<lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock" />` to your appender section of the config and also try logging something in your Register method.

Comment: Permission issue on the folder "C:\logs"?